# How to Open Facebook auth dialog every time?

Tags: android, parsing, parse-platform

I am using ParseFacebookUtils to login through facebook,with this code i successfully logged in through Facebook and got all data of user.

But if Facebook native application is installed on my phone facebook auth dialog is not called every time and went in User is null condition. See following code i used :

```
    ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(Arrays.asList(Permissions.Friends.ACTIVITIES),
                    this, new LogInCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {

                    if(user == null){

System.out.println(" Here");    

                    }else if(user.isNew()){

                    }else{

    }
```

But i want to open Facebook auth dialog every time that will return me any ParseUser.
How to achieve this kind of funcationality ?

Note :

1. I checked my Facebook KeyHash and Facebook AppID is correct.
2. I used Facebook sdk 3.0 and parse sdk 1.2.3

I dont know how to achieve this IN my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Session session = ParseFacebookUtils.getSession();
if (session != null)
    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();

ParseUser.logOut();
```

This will finish your Facebook session on curren machine. Next time when you ry login - F login dialog will appear.